# Login to Facebook with out User Interaction In Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-facebook

i know how to log in face book using Facebook SDK. Can we log in facebook with preset of User Name and password (No user interaction). If so please post any tutorial for that. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible because Facebook requires the user to allow permission for your app, so the user needs to enter the username and password.

Comment: Thank u. can we post predefined string as a a status with out user interaction?

Comment: Yes, you can but you need to use the Facebook SDK. Establish a token and use that token to post the status.

Answer (score 0):

Right now its not possible but here is some unethical hack I can think of:

run an automation script at night on users phone,probably when the phone is ideal,which does following thing:

1)launches your app

2)launches fb authorization dialog

3)clicks on authorize button

4)Stores the access token for further use

Comment: You won't be able to do that as their authorization dialog Intent opens the Facebook's internal app (or website if it's not installed on the device) which you have absolutely no control over. Plus, they will ban your app for that kind of activity.

Comment: @Guardanis you can fire the intent(same intent which you would normally do for legitimate authorization) through the script which will launch fb dialog..

Comment: Yeah, and then the user would have to explicitly authorize (or, if not logged in, login and then authorize) the app to use your Facebook account. Once you've launched the Intent you're no longer 'within your own app' (loosely using terminology) and no longer have control, so there's no way for you to automatically do what you're saying.

Comment: @Guardanis our script will inject button click event on the fb dialog,no need of user interaction..this is the way we automate functional test cases

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but how exactly are you planning on "injecting" that click when the user is no longer inside your app? You can't inject an event into another application on a non-rooted Android without the INJECT_EVENTS permission, which is reserved as a system-level permission and can't be used by regular apps. You could do direct event injection on a rooted device, but that's not really helpful.

Comment: you can inject events within the your app..so when the fb dialog is launched i feel it will be part of your app so you cna do it using internal apis..follow-http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.U-lA5x_D9mM

Comment: Yeah, the key there is "within your own app," but once you've launched the Intent for Facebook you're no longer within your app, you're either within Facebook's or whatever browser was opened

Comment: that is if you do it with facebook sdk..but if you do it using plan OAuth apis you can do it within your own webview..refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1